# Zabbix 5 API call to enable or disable host

Tags: api, triggers, action, host, zabbix

I am trying to enable or disable when there is a certain trigger. Can anyone give me a hint to do this?
I know that I can use "action" to run certain command or script when there is a trigger triggered.
I barely have an idea where to start to do this.

Comment: You should start from the documentation (quick start: https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/quickstart - api: https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/api), write your own code then ask for help

Comment: I have my api code ready but I need help calling the api as an action in Zabbix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Action - Operations documentation](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/config/notifications/action/operation/remote_command):

> With remote commands you can define that a certain pre-defined command
> is automatically executed on the monitored host upon some condition.

And:

> Configuring an action for remote commands is similar to that for
> sending a message, the only difference being that Zabbix will execute
> a command instead of sending a message.
>
> Remote commands can be executed by Zabbix server, proxy or agent.
> Remote commands on Zabbix agent can be executed directly by Zabbix
> server or through Zabbix proxy.

Also, there are examples in the page.

Comment: I know that commands are available remotely. But is it possible to call an API call through Zabbix server command? I can't just type in the json in the command section.

Comment: Just create a script in Python or similar, then use an action to launch it from the Zabbix server

Comment: you can create a script to do this job. Use one of these libraries https://zabbix.org/wiki/Docs/api/libraries

Comment: oh i needed a python script in order to use the api. now i got it. thank you so so much!